# How to export data from oracle forms 10g to Excel and PDF File directly?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

My manager asks me to find solution about export database data from oracle forms 10g to Excel and PDF File directly open. I am new in this field and i have no knowledge about that how to export data into excel or pdf file.I am using oracle forms 10g with ERP System. Please suggest me possible solution.

Thanks

Comment: Try any of these: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/147685/2/. Or try Google, which you apparently didn't do beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need it in pdf the easiest way is to use jasperreports.
It is easy to setup and can create directly pdf documents.